# error TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am using `"typescript"- "3.8.3"`, `"mongoose": "5.9.11"`

My code was working on version `"typescript": "3.4.x"`, `"mongoose": "4.x"`.

my code snippet is follows:
[image]

where `Collections` is as below:

```
export let Collections = {
  identity: "identities",
  calllog: "calllog",
  calllogs: "calllogs"
};
```

I went through some related bug> [TypeScript/issues/31663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31663) but did not got a fair idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the type passed to model<**any**> and Schema

I created interface as follows:

```
import {Document, Types} from "mongoose";
export interface CallLogsInterface extends Document {
    user: Types.ObjectId,
    logs: Types.ObjectId []
}
```

And passed interface to model:

```
export const ModelCalllogs = model<CallLogsInterface>(
  Collections.calllogs,
  new Schema<CallLogsInterface>({
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: Collections.identity
    },
    logs: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: Collections.calllog
    }]
  })
);
```

Boom it started working.